# MySQL display statistics grouped by time slot

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by

I have one table called reservation with such fields:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`begin_time` datetime NOT NULL,
`end_time` datetime NOT NULL,
`node_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

I wish to show statistics about reservations during a given time period (say $from - $until, values coming from php). A user books one node with each reservation. There are many nodes which can be booked and I use the following query to show reservation statistics by date.

```
SELECT DATE(begin_time) `Date`, count(id) as reservations
FROM reservation
WHERE begin_time > '" . $from . "'
AND end_time < '" . $until . "'
GROUP BY Date"
```

Now I want to give statistics on which time period during the day is more active. The 24 hours of a day are divided in 48 thirty-minute slots. In my table, all the begin_date and end_date values are round numbers like 2011-04-11 20:00:00 or 2011-04-11 14:30:00. Reservations can have a duration of 30 minutes, 60 minutes, etc until 4 hours maximum.

I would like my statistics to be in the following format (more or less)

```
    Time slot       | reservations
----------------------------------
00:00:00 - 00:30:00 |     23
00:30:00 - 01:00:00 |     12
01:00:00 - 01:30:00 |     20
01:30:00 - 02:00:00 |     66
02:00:00 - 02:30:00 |     12
                and so on
```

Can you help me with the SQL query?

**Edit:** I see now that PostgreSQL has some range types and operators, for example <@  (range is contained by) [documentation here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/functions-range.html). Does this mean that my query would be easier if I used Postgres? Does MySQL have something similar?

**Edit 2:** Thank you, tombom. Actually, I changed your answer, removing DATE(begin_time) AS `Date` from the select clause and the group by clause, because I wanted to see which hours of the day are the most active *over a period of many days*. And I can live with having 1 hour granularity instead of 30 mins.
But I would like to ask you what exactly you mean with your first sentence. If a reservation starts at 01:00:00 and it ends at 03:00:00 I do in fact want it to be counted on both time slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my table, all the begin_date and end_date values are round numbers like 2011-04-11 20:00:00 or 2011-04-11 14:30:00

Unless you also have times like `2011-04-11 14:15:00` your desired result with steps of 30 minutes doesn't make much sense, unless you want to count some reservations two times.

Apart from that in MySQL it would be something like this:

```
SELECT 
DATE(begin_time) AS `Date`,
CASE 
WHEN TIME(begin_time) >= '00:00:00' AND TIME(begin_time) < '01:00:00' THEN '00:00:00 - 01:00:00' 
WHEN TIME(begin_time) >= '01:00:00' AND TIME(begin_time) < '02:00:00' THEN '01:00:00 - 02:00:00' 
/*...and so on...*/
END AS `TimeSlot`,
COUNT(id) as reservations
FROM reservation
WHERE begin_time > '" . $from . "'
AND end_time < '" . $until . "'
GROUP BY `Date`, `TimeSlot`
```

I made it time slots of 1 hour and added the date to be grouped on.

Actually, silly me, now that I think about it, when you have time slots of exactly one hour, you can also do it like this:

```
SELECT 
DATE(begin_time) AS `Date`,
HOUR(begin_time) AS `TimeSlot`,
COUNT(id) as reservations
FROM reservation
WHERE begin_time > '" . $from . "'
AND end_time < '" . $until . "'
GROUP BY `Date`, `TimeSlot`
```

**UPDATE:**

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN TIME(begin_time) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '01:00:00' OR TIME(end_time) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '01:00:00' THEN '00:00:00 - 01:00:00' 
WHEN TIME(begin_time) BETWEEN '01:00:00' AND '02:00:00' OR TIME(end_time) BETWEEN '01:00:00' AND '02:00:00' THEN '01:00:00 - 02:00:00' 
/*...and so on...*/
END AS `TimeSlot`,
COUNT(id) as reservations
FROM reservation
WHERE begin_time > '" . $from . "'
AND end_time < '" . $until . "'
GROUP BY `TimeSlot`
```